# Incorrect percent symbol in Google rich snippets and testing tool

Tags: google-rich-snippets

Why does Google show the rating percent symbol as HTML entity code?
In the base search results the percent symbol shows correct, but in rich snippets it is encoded.

This bug available in Google testing tool also.

For example, JSON-LD for Google Structured Data Testing Tool: https://gist.github.com/ZhandosKz/996308ef58fbd8382203f6843a81231e

In preview we will see:

[image: snippet preview]